# How to delete Prefect blocks in Python?

Tags: python, prefect

I am using Prefect 2.

I am able to create Prefect blocks, for example, AWS Credentials and Kubernetes Job blocks by

```py
from prefect_aws import AwsCredentials
from prefect.infrastructure import KubernetesJob

async def create():
    await AwsCredentials(
        aws_access_key_id="xxx",
        aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
        region_name="us-west-2",
    ).save(f"my-aws-credentials-block", overwrite=True)

    await KubernetesJob(
        image=f"my-image:latest",
        image_pull_policy="Always",
    ).save(f"my-kubernetes-job-block", overwrite=True)
```

Now I am hoping to delete them in Python.

I was trying to find how to at

- https://prefecthq.github.io/prefect-kubernetes/
- https://prefecthq.github.io/prefect-aws/

but didn't find any info.

Is there a way to delete Prefect blocks by Python code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can delete a Prefect block in Python like this:

```
from prefect import get_client

async with get_client() as client:
      block_document = await client.read_block_document_by_name(
          name="my-block", block_type_slug="string"
      )
      await client.delete_block_document(block_document.id)
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/9755) to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the prefect UI and go to blocks section there as well you can delete